# Ignore RProfile when running R CMD batch on windows

Tags: r, cmd

I want to create `bat` files which will run R scripts on coworkers' computers, to test them I wish to bypass my RProfile.

I'm using the following code :

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\R.exe" --vanilla CMD BATCH "mypath\myscript.R"
```

I expected that  `--vanilla` would make it ignore the RProfile, however, I see in the `myscript.Rout` file created by the script some custom output which indicates that it went through it.

How can I run this R script in a clean session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the option in the wrong place.  It goes after `BATCH`:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla "mypath\myscript.R"
```

See the help page `?BATCH` or at the command line `R CMD BATCH --help` for more details and options.